# Having trouble getting a regex to redirect traffic to work correctly

Tags: web-hosting, regex, 301-redirect

I'm trying to setup some 301 redirects on WPengine using regex and I'm having trouble getting things working.

- **Old URL:** https://www.website.com/abc/123
- **New URL:** https://www.website.com/abc

For pages that do not have the first part of the URL matching, I'm able to setup things up using the below:

- **Source:** ^/abc/123/
- **Destination:** ^/def/

However, when I set this up using the Old/New URL listeded above, this creates a circular reference so it does not work.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a regex expression that tells does **not** redirect the URL for /abc to itself, creating a circular direction.

The documentation from WPengine for this is here: https://wpengine.com/support/regex/

I've tried a bunch of different things and can't quite figure this one out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - adding the solution for anybody who may need it in the future!

- **Source:** ^/abc/(.+)
- **Destination:** ^/abc/